# Which method is the least obtrusive for generating thread dumps in java?

Tags: performance, jvm, thread-dump

I am aware of the following methods for generating thread dumps in java:

- kill -3
- jstack
- JMX from inside the JVM
- JMX remote
- JPDA (remote)
- JVMTI (C API)

Of these methods, which is the least detrimental to the JVM's performance?

Answer (score 8):

If you just need to dump all stack traces to *stdout*, `kill -3` and `jstack` should be the cheapest. The functionality is implemented natively in JVM code. No intermediate structures are created - the VM prints everything itself while it walks through the stacks.

Both commands perform the same VM operation except that signal handler prints stack traces locally to *stdout* of Java process, while `jstack` receives the output from the target VM through IPC (*Unix domain socket* on Linux or *Named Pipe* on Windows).

`jstack` uses [Dynamic Attach](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/docs/Serviceability.html#battach) mechanism under the hood. You can also utilize Dynamic Attach directly if you wish to receive the stack traces as a plain stream of bytes.

```
import com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine;
import sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class StackTrace {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String pid = args[0];
        HotSpotVirtualMachine vm = (HotSpotVirtualMachine) VirtualMachine.attach(pid);

        try (InputStream in = vm.remoteDataDump()) {
            byte[] buf = new byte[8000];
            for (int bytes; (bytes = in.read(buf)) > 0; ) {
                System.out.write(buf, 0, bytes);
            }
        } finally {
            vm.detach();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that all of the mentioned methods operate in a VM safepoint anyway. This means that all Java threads are stopped while the stack traces are collected.

Answer (score 0):

The most performant option is likely to be the use of the ThreadMXBean.dumpAllThreads() API rather than requesting a text thread dump written to disk:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html#dumpAllThreads(boolean,%20boolean)

Of course, whether you can use that depends on whether you need a thread dump file, or just the data.

Comment: This is the worst option actually. Java-land representation of the stacktrace `ThreadInfo[]` requires a large amount of heap memory and takes much time to get constructed and printed.