# How to capture the Java threads dump automatically based on some conditions?

Tags: jvm

Suppose I want to capture the threads dump by Jmap or alternative ways automatically when the number of tomcat threads over 500,how to achieve it?

BTW, the environment is Linux CentOS.

Comment: What is the problem? Monitor the number of Tomcat threads through JMX and whenever it reaches a threshold, execute jstack.

Comment: We have a tomcat Application, and it's threads number often increased to a large number at randomly time in short time, it would last some minutes(meaning we often no time to capture the thread dump manually),  then dropped  .I want to see what's happens for these threads. so you mean I need to write a JMX  program, and invokes the jstack from the JMX program when issue happens?

Comment: As I have no idea how to run tool jstack  from the JMX program. Running the shell script ,which invokes the Jstack , from the Java code?

Comment: Yes; why not. There are [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795573/which-method-is-the-least-obtrusive-for-generating-thread-dumps-in-java/26810701#26810701) to make a thread dump, but `Runtime.exec` is just easier.